# Installing virtualenv without root

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to install virtualenv on a machine without root access. Note that I don't have pip either on the machine, so "pip install --user virtualenv" won't work (unless I want to install pip locally as well).

I tried the following:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/d4/0c/9840c08189e030873387a73b90ada981885010dd9aea134d6de30cd24cb8/virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz#md5=44e19f4134906fe2d75124427dc9b716
tar zvf virtualenv-15.1.0.tar.gz
python virtualenv-15.1.0/virtualenv.py venv
```

And got an error message:

```
Cannot find a wheel for setuptools
Cannot find a wheel for pip
```

Does this mean I need to install setuptools and pip first? But installing everything (pip and virtualenv) under "~/.local" didn't work either. I also tried using "extra-search-dir" option for virtualenv.

Related Questions:
 [How to Install virtualenv on a machine without root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003691/how-to-install-virtualenv-on-a-machine-without-root-access?s=2|1.6489)

Comment: you need setuptools to configure your module for your system so yes you need setuptools

Comment: There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942925/3848833 mentioning your problem.